# Data from MySQL database being shown in text field but not in text area via php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get data from my database in MySQL in a form that has two fields i.e for `Title` and `Content`.

When I try to get the data and keep the text fields as input type, the data in content does show up but then it shown only the starting part of the data. The reason for that I am guessing is that input tag only allows a limited characters.

Now when I try to get the data in a textarea tag, the data simply doesn't show up.

**edit_post.php**

```
<?php include 'db.php'; ?>

<?php
    $query = 'Select * from post';
    $messages = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>edit</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>MessageApp</h1>

        </header>
        <div class="main">

            <form method="POST" action="db.php" >
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($messages)): ?>
                <input type="text" name="text" value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>">
                <input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo $row['content']; ?>">
                <!--<textarea name="user" value="<?php echo $row['content']; ?>"></textarea>-->
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit">

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </form>
            <hr>

        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php


$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms');

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    echo 'DB connection error:'.mysqli_connect_error();

?>
```

I have commented out the textarea type. The input type above it does show data but when I try to call it in a text area, it doesn't show up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `<textarea name="user"><?php echo $row['content']; ?></textarea>` ?

Comment: Textarea does not have `value`, you simply output content between tags. Also make sure your database does not truncates input field (usually it's only 255 chars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data should be added be between text area opening and closing tag as textarea doesn't accept value

Change your code to below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>edit</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>MessageApp</h1>

        </header>
        <div class="main">

            <form method="POST" action="db.php" >
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($messages)): ?>
                <input type="text" name="text" value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>">
                <input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo $row['content']; ?>">
                <textarea name="user"><?php echo $row['content']; ?></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit">

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </form>
            <hr>

        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`textarea` doesn't have `value=""` attribute as other form inputs, so try this:

```
<textarea name="user" ><?php echo $row['content']; ?></textarea>
```

You must have to put your text between `textarea` starting and closing tags like other tags `div`and `p`. I hope it helps